# Can I put an expired certification on my resume?

Tags: resume, certification

I had a Cisco cert that expired about a year ago. I let it expire because I wasn't working with the technology day to day in my current job, but now I am. I'd like to be able to put it on my resume as expired and then say I'm planning to re-certify.

My reasoning is instead of just saying "I plan to achieve this certification in the near future" I can say I already had this certification which I'm hoping would carry more weight?

I was going to put it under my skills or education section with (expired) next to it and then somewhere in my resume give a time frame of when I plan to certify again.

What do you think?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can put an expired certification. The piece of paper may be expired, but your knowledge is never expired.

I would list the certification under education and in parentheses say (expired, currently renewing). Keep the words short and concise, and use lots of white space. Most importantly, stress in you cover-letter what you accomplished in your current position and how you will accomplish those things (and more) if you get selected for this new position.

While certifications are important, knowledge and your hard work is much much more valuable.

Comment: Agreed. My Cisco certs expired - I wasn't going to kill myself on that Cisco cert treadmill. Your Cisco cert expired but it's still a useful frame of reference when it comes to gauging your level of knowledge. Having said that, I am glad that I am a Linux guy - I just hate those paper certifications and those - Microsoft, Cisco, CISSP, etc. - who issue them.

Comment: I agree, as certs become less valuable it seems like more and more of just a money grab for the companies issuing them. Feel bad for all those Microsoft Certified Masters- $10,000 well spent.

Comment: @user1028270 --- It depends what you get out of studying those certs. Many sites advertise question dumps but if a person applies themselves to learn and understand the study material, and it shows when they perform their job, then I believe certs are worth it. And the knowledge you get from learning plus applying what you learn will soon outweigh the money spent to take these exams. It's unfortunate that certs have been misused because people want a piece of paper that says they know something when all they did was memorize question and answers.

Comment: @user1028270 Certs range a great deal in value. The A+ for example covers things that are more and more becoming "common knowledge" which has made it all but worthless. On the other hand certs like the CCNA still retain a great deal of value, albeit not on as broad a level. It used to be if you had a CCNA you could practically walk in and take a job from someone without a CCNA regardless of the infrastructure. (It was just that valuable) Nowadays if the company has a Cisco backend that CCNA is still gold, but if they aren't on Cisco... meh... a plus still, but a pretty small one.

Comment: I wholly agree that putting an expired cert on your resume is perfectly acceptable.  In IT, the fundamentals of a certification change very slowly.  Having the cert, even if expired shows that knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it on your resume if you look at it like an achievement. As long as you don't put "Current certifications" or something similar then you're in an ethically gray area because you're not saying you currently hold those certifications specifically, though you are allowing them to infer that.

Normally I'm a complete tight-ass on stuff except with certifications you've still acquired the knowledge and that's still valid and you're showing that you did in fact demonstrate to a testing service that you did acquire that knowledge, even if the testing service isn't testifying to it anymore.

There is an exception though. If the position you're applying for states in its description or you learn through the interview that a specific certification is required then you're ethically obligated (in my opinion) to tell them that it's expired and you're in the process of recertifying, which should be a simple matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your certificates show that you have done something that'll be helpful for you in near future and confirms that you have some knowledge about the field.
Considering that it might be just a piece of paper for some but it is bound to be valued at right place.
Since you have not been working in the field related to certificate and think of shifting to that again I suggest you to be ready to face some questions relating to you technology change .

> Your specifying the certificate will help you in changing the
>   technology as it'll show that  you have some prior knowledge and
>   showing that you are think of renewing the certificate shows your
>   interest in the field.